# Double confirmation for deleting ITEM from DB?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-applications, web

I want to delete a huge records for a button click from DB .hard delete .My requirement is to prompt user twice before deleting .
1.Are you want to delete ?? by confirm box wheich i have already done 
2.From cs page in button click like "are you sure to delete 500 items"

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReviewAll" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Review All" 
                        CssClass="button" ToolTip="Click to Review All" OnClick="btnReviewAll_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:return  confirm('Are you sure want to Review all Closed Items??');" />
```

in button click in .cs page i am getting record count ..how to prompt user for proceed and show in any confirmation box.

```
protected void btnReviewAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               List<Items> lstWorkItems = objBPC.GetCurrentWorkItems();
               //what to write here

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Utils.DisplayMasterError(this.Page.Master, ex);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using javascript function

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReviewAll" 
Visible="false" 
runat="server" 
Text="Review All" 
CssClass="button" 
ToolTip="Click to Review All" 
OnClick="btnReviewAll_Click" 
OnClientClick="javascript:confirmation();" />


<script>
function confirmation() {

    var yes = confirm("Are you sure want to delete that");

    if (yes) {

        var confirmyes = confirm("do you want to confirm delte");

        if (confirmyes) {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Actually i have to show number of deleted item count which i can not hard coded in js

Answer (score 0):

Found this when trying to get double confirmation working. The code posted by Rafee didnt seem to work. W3C stated `The confirm() method returns true if the user clicked "OK", and false otherwise.`

So here's what I used;

```
    $('.disableConfirm').on('click', function(){

        if ( confirm('Confirm 1') ) {

            if ( confirm('Confirm 2') ){
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;

    });
```